# Search4 Selector with not Resolving Correctly in MySQL

Tags: acumatica

I have added a new field called UsrStockLocation to the SOLine DAC, this field has a selector that searches all past entries and shows them without duplicates. This worked in 2017R2 and works in 2018R2 if the Acumatica site is using MSSQL, however, if the 2018R2 site is using MySQL I receive this error when I click the magnifying glass on the field:

`Unknown column 'SOLineExtension.UsrStockLocation' in 'field list'`

It looks like Acumatica is passing the class name from the DAC extension on to the DB instead of SOLine. The column UsrStockLocation is created properly in the SOLine table in the DB.

Here is the code for the DAC extension:

```
using PX.Data;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOLineExtension : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine>
  {
    #region Stock Location
    [PXDBString()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Stock Location")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search4<SOLineExtension.usrStockLocation, Where<SOLineExtension.usrStockLocation, IsNotNull>, Aggregate<GroupBy<SOLineExtension.usrStockLocation>>>), ValidateValue = false)]
    [PXCustomizeSelectorColumns(typeof(SOLineExtension.usrStockLocation))]
    public virtual string UsrStockLocation { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrStockLocation : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Is there a different way that I am supposed to do this for MySQL vs MSSQL?

Comment: I suspect it's a bug where the ORM fails to compose Aggregate clause that contains Custom fields. Not much you can do besides filling in a support ticket.

Comment: I suggest you test the same request but with a non custom field in the aggregate group by. If it doesn't fail then it's even more likely that the ORM fails to compose aggregate clause containing custom fields. This was a known issue that have been fixed, perhaps it pass through the cracks for MYSQL and is not 100% fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and update